# Aliasing locales in Next.js

Tags: next.js, i18next

I'm using `next-i18next` to localize our Next.js app with the following config:

```js
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: "en",
    locales: ["en", "zh-CN"],
  },
};
```

This works well. Agents with `zh-CN` among `Allow-Language` header are taken to the Simplified Chinese version of the page.

Is there a way to make `zh-SG` agents redirect to the Simplified Chinese version without creating a separate locale JSON file? Similarly, `zh-HK` and `zh-TW` will use the same translations (Traditional Chinese). I'm trying to avoid maintaining duplicate files by only having one file for Simplified and one for Traditional Chinese. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `fallbackLng`. Something like this: `fallbackLng: {default:['en'], 'zh-SG':['zn-CN'], 'zh-HK':['zn-CN']}`.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! If you can submit you answer I'll accept it 

Comment: fix tye typo: `fallbackLng: {default:['en'], 'zh-SG':['zh-CN'], 'zh-HK':['zh-CN']}`